# Live update Plotly DatePickerSingle component

Tags: datepicker, plotly-dash, plotly-python

How do I show my desired date range when the user refreshes the webpage?

I want my DatePickerSingle component to update always have a shown date range between today() - 4 days AND today(). My app is launched on a server once and always stays launched. No restarting.

The DatePickerSingle is used in a callback function for them to select a date to show the data for the id='tbl-output'.

The code below gives me an "error loading layout". I believe its because the id='date-picker' component isn't in the right place. But when I take out the id from the function definition and put it in the app.layout, it still doesn't work right.

```
def daterange():
    return  dcc.DatePickerSingle(
                   id='date-picker',
                   min_date_allowed = datetime.now().date() - timedelta(days=4),
                   max_date_allowed = datetime.now().date(),
                   date = datetime.now().date(),
                   display_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD')

app = dash.Dash(__name__, url_base_pathname='/portal/pl/')
app.layout = html.Div([
        html.Div( 
            daterange,
            style={'display': 'inline-block'}),
        html.Div( 
            html.H1('Continuum P&L'),
            style={'textAlign': 'center',
                       'color': 'green',
                       'display': 'inline-block',
                       'margin-left': '10px'}),
        html.Div(id='tbl_output')
        ])

@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='tbl_output', component_property='children'),
    [Input(component_id='date-picker', component_property='date')]
)
```

When I have the app.layout as shown below, the app works, but the selectable dates don't change with time. The date range stays according to when the app was launched on the server.

```
app = dash.Dash(__name__, url_base_pathname='/portal/pl/')
app.layout = html.Div([
        html.Div( 
            dcc.DatePickerSingle(
                id='date-picker',
                min_date_allowed = datetime.now().date() - timedelta(days=4),
                max_date_allowed = datetime.now().date(),
                date = datetime.now().date(),
                display_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD'),
            style={'display': 'inline-block'}),
        html.Div( 
            html.H1('Continuum P&L'),
            style={'textAlign': 'center',
                       'color': 'green',
                       'display': 'inline-block',
                       'margin-left': '10px'}),
        html.Div(id='tbl_output')
        ])

@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='tbl_output', component_property='children'),
    [Input(component_id='date-picker', component_property='date')]
)
def freshdf(date):
    result=connection.execute(query)
    df=pd.DataFrame(result.fetchall())
    date = datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d').date()
    df=df[df['pricedate'] == date]
    df.columns=result.keys()
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The code below gives me an "error loading layout".

The error is raised because of the following line:

```py
html.Div(daterange, style={"display": "inline-block"})
```

`daterange` is a function, while is should be a list of (or a single) dash component.  `html.Div(daterange(),...)` should fix it.

> The date range stays according to when the app was launched on the server.

In order to solve this issue, you should take advantage of the initial call of the callbacks. See [the "When a Dash App First Loads" section of the Advanced Callbacks documentation](https://dash.plotly.com/advanced-callbacks) for more details.

You can leave the `dcc.DatePickerSingle` dates empty and create a callback to set the `min_date_allowed`, `max_date_allowed`, and `date` properties when the app first load in the client browser.

```py
def daterange():
    return dcc.DatePickerSingle(
        id="date-picker",
        display_format="YYYY-MM-DD",
    )
```

```py
@app.callback(
    Output("date-picker", "date"),
    Output("date-picker", "min_date_allowed"),
    Output("date-picker", "max_date_allowed"),
    Input("date-picker", "display_format"),
)
def set_date_picker(_):
    today = datetime.now().date()
    min_date_allowed = today - timedelta(days=4)
    max_date_allowed = today

    return today, min_date_allowed, max_date_allowed
```

That way, each time a client access to the app, the date picker parameters will be set according to the current date (not the one at which the app has been launched)

---

> The DatePickerSingle is used in a callback function for them to select a date to show the data for the id='tbl-output'.

I would use a `dash_table.DataTable` component to display the data linked to the selected date. Here is a very basic example, you'll find more info in [the corresponding doc](https://dash.plotly.com/datatable)

- A basic dataframe `df` just for test purposes

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 2023-06-20 00:00:00 |
| 1 | 2 | 2023-06-19 00:00:00 |
| 2 | 3 | 2023-06-18 00:00:00 |
| 3 | 4 | 2023-06-17 00:00:00 |

- Change the `html.Div` object for a `dash_table.DataTable` in the layout

```py
dash_table.DataTable(id="tbl_output"),
```

- Change the callback signature to change the DataTable `data` properties

```py
@app.callback(
    Output(component_id="tbl_output", component_property="data"),
    Input(component_id="date-picker", component_property="date"),
)
def freshdf(date):
    target_date = pd.to_datetime(date)
    selected_df = df[df["B"] == target_date]
    return selected_df.to_dict("records")
```

Comment: I incorporated your answer into my code, but now I cannot change the date in the DatePickerSingle. I go to click on an available date, but the display always goes back to today. And the second component  (referenced by id='tbl_output') needs that date to display its data.

Comment: To be clear, I added your second code block just below my original app.layout, and revised my daterange formula to your suggestion. There is still the original callback from my question in my code, too.

Comment: My bad, the `date` property to trigger the initialization callback was a poor choice. I've updated my answer to target the `display_format` property - which is not supposed to change through the app lifetime.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you want to achieve with the `tbl_output`, but it looks specific to your data. The callback signature looks good to me, make sure you `return` the value you want. Maybe use a `DataTable` to display the selected dataframe.

Comment: I've updated the answer with an example to display the rows associated with the selected date, for a given base dataframe.

Comment: The change to the component_property="display_format" was the trick. It all works now.